# Ruby: How do I join elements of an array together with a prefix?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have an array like so:

```
["marblecake", "also", "the", 1337]
```

I would like to get back a string which contains each element of the array prefixed by some specified string, then joined together by another specified string. For example,

```
["marblecake", "also", "the", 1337].join_with_prefix("%", "__")
```

should result in

```
# => %marblecake__%also__%the__%1337
```

How might I do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If your array is in `a` then this one-liner will do it

```
a.map { |k| "%#{k}" }.join("_")
```

You could easily put this in a function of your own - even add it to the `Array` class so that you can call it on an array, like in your example.

Note that the '!' version of map (`map!`) will modify the array in place - perhaps not your intent.

Comment: Why are you using the destructive, in-place version of "map"? Depending on what the OP's code looks like, that could have some unintended side effects.

Comment: Jason: Only primitives/strings are being stored here. Is there an alternative you'd recommend?

Comment: "map" returns a new array. "map!" modifies the array that it's called on, and returns the same array. So if you have code that does. "a.map! { ... something ... }" and then later you reference "a" again, you'll find that the elements of "a" have been replaced with the result of the "map!" block, which you may or may not want. Unless you have a specific reason not to, I would just use "map", which returns a new array and doesn't touch the existing one.

Comment: Jason, you're right, the bang version is destructive. I guess I figured that the coder would know the difference and implement appropriately. Maybe that is an unsafe assumption :)

Answer (score 11):

Although this is very old question, I'd like to add this:

```
a.any? && "%".+(a.join("__%"))
```

Comment: That's a smart solution! I like this very much :)

Comment: if `a` is empty then this will returns `%` only

Answer (score 2):

As per the above suggestion:

```
class Array
  def join_with_prefix(prefix,separator)
    self.collect {|e| prefix.to_s + e }.join(separator)
  end
end

p ['ab','cd','ef'].join_with_prefix('%','__')
```

```
=> "%ab__%cd__%ef"
```

Comment: This assumes you are trying to join an array of strings - if you had an array of integers for instance than the " + e" part would fail as there as the "+" is not implemented for string + integer. A better approach would be to do the string concatenation in a double-quoted string with an string interpolation "#{e}" which would implicitly to_s your element, hence:

self.collect {|e| "#{prefix}#{e}" }.join(separator)

Its more flexible.

Comment: Or you could just do `prefix.to_s + e.to_s`

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a solution to this today.I found this question.This was my solution.

```
array = ["marblecake", "also", "the", 1337];
arrayString = ''

array.each{|x| arrayString += "%" + x + "__"}
```