# Dynamic string generation with depending on size of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I need to generate a string based on an array of ids.

#### Array

```
["5d227c01-93dc-4f0b-abca-2f1686b6f15c", "71c20c13-ddda-4177-ac9b-cf4096577450"]
```

So this array could obviously be anything, but I need to take each element and generate a string that looks like this.

#### String

```
"ManagerID='5d227c01-93dc-4f0b-abca-2f1686b6f15c' OR ManagerID='71c20c13-ddda-4177-ac9b-cf4096577450'"
```

I'm finding this hard because I have to add the `OR` after each ID but not after the last one and none if there is only 1 ID

It looks something like this

#### Code

```
def normalized_manager_ids
  if manager_id_list.count <= 1
    "ManagerID='#{manager_id_list.first}'"
  else
    manager_id_list.map do |id|
      # GENERATE STRING HERE BASED ON HOW MANY IDS THERE ARE
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a database query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: How do I join elements of an array together with a prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803384/ruby-how-do-i-join-elements-of-an-array-together-with-a-prefix)

Comment: Note that your example code returns `"ManagerID=''"` if the array is empty.

Comment: What is `manager_id_list`? Presumable it's a method as it's not an argument of the method. Could the array contain zero, one or more than two elements, or is it always two?

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g.,  `arr = ["5d227c01-93...]`) . That way, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Of course, there's no need to assign variables to objects that are expected return values.

Comment: use `array.map { |x| "ManagerID='#{x}'" }.join(' OR ')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def normalized_manager_ids
  if manager_id_list.count <= 1
    "ManagerID='#{manager_id_list.first}'"
  else
    manager_id_list.map{ |id| "ManagerID='#{id}'" }.join(" OR ")
  end
end
```

or even shorter:

```
def normalized_manager_ids
  manager_id_list.map{ |id| "ManagerID='#{id}'" }.join(" OR ")
end
```

However, if you wan't to use this in SQL query, I would rather recommend using SQL `IN` operator instead - for example:

```
.where("ManagerID IN (?)", manager_id_list)
```

Comment: `where(ManagerID: manager_id_list)` should work as well, no placeholder needed. Be aware that when inlining data into SQL you **must** properly escape things, something that's not done in your first two examples.